# How to parameterize a custom SSIS component

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am developing a custom SSIS component, a data source to be precise. Now, I have almost everything in place - the component takes one input parameter (custom property), which is a string. As this parameter will change depending on the environment, it is crucial for me to parameterize it with an expression that would assign it a value from a package parameter.

[image: Component parameters]

Of course when I right-click on my component in the data flow, there is no "Parameterize..." option. I noticed that in commercial components, such as Cozyroc, it is handled through data flow property expressions, but my "Process URL" is not visible as a property that could be assigned with an expression.

[image: Data flow property expressions]

How can I enable parameterization on my custom property? I am using SQL Server 2012 as a target platform for my projects, the component itself is written in C#.

Comment: It would be great to add more detail (aka code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your custom property for **Process URL**, you should set its property `.ExpressionType = DTSCustomPropertyExpressionType.CPET_NOTIFY`. More details you can find here in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/data-flow/design-time-methods-of-a-data-flow-component) on Custom Data Flow component.
Once you set this, your custom property will be available at DataFlow expressions.